# How to total the values of textbox having same class and put it inside the another textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can i total the value of all textbox having class `1` , `2` and `3` and put it inside `sum_1`, `sum_2` and `sum_3`

I tried with this way

Jquery here :

```
   $(document).on("change", ".1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

HTML here :

```
<input type="text" class="1" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="2" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="3" value="5" />
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/36/ which works good for one value

But how can i do this for 3 values like i asked in the question which is given in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vL6f2tow/1/

### Update :

And how can i get those values of sum in a total

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to your question; don't rely on us being willing to explore other sites (even JS Fiddle) to find your code. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: you forgot to add the jquery in your second fiddle link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it on load you should probably do something like this

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice( itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1 );
    var sumElement = $(".sum_" + itemNumber);
    var sum = (sumElement.val() == "") ? 0 : parseInt(sumElement.val());
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    sumElement.val(sum);
});
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vL6f2tow/18/) to calculate local sums

If you want to calculate a global sum (sum of local sums) here is a [**demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vL6f2tow/23/)

---

If you have multiple of such group of inputs then you have to add a class to each of these inputs so that you know which input elements you need to consider to calculate the sum for.

```
<input type="text" class="item 1" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="3" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="4" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="6" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="7" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="sum_1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="sum_2" value="" />
<input type="text" class="sum_3" value="" />



 $(document).on("change", ".item", function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice( itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1 );
    $('.'+itemNumber).each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $(".sum_" + itemNumber).val(sum);
});
```

In the above script,

1. $(this).attr('class') will looks like "item 1"
2. $(this).attr('class').split(" ") will be an array ["item", "1"]
3. Then i'm removing the word `item` and using that `"1"`

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vL6f2tow/16/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i am having that textbox in php foreach function and i don't even know how many textbox it will have,, so shall i use this kind?

Comment: yes, it should work for the scenario you explained. Please check the updated answer

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Please make sure you have added `item` as class. Also please make sure that the jquery code is just above the closing body tag </body>

Comment: It is working.. but the entire function is in onchange.. how can i change it in document ready itself

Comment: +1 for your answer... but I tried like this http://jsfiddle.net/vL6f2tow/17/ but didn't suceed. Can i change it in document ready and it should also work on onchange the items..

Comment: updated my answer with another demo in the top, please check that

Comment: In the fiddle your provided, the value is showing correct at starting but not changing in the on change event

Comment: the second fiddle is `only` if you want to do everything on load. If you want a combination of both then you just have to combine both scripts like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vL6f2tow/20/

Comment: Thanks, It worked great.. May i know how to add those total of `sum_1` `sum_2` to n number of `sum_n` and have it in the text box called as `total` like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vL6f2tow/22/

Comment: Hi, i have a small doubt in this, actually i have to do same thing in another div, is it possible to use repeat the same code while i use items and sums (just adding s to the inputs and renaming it in script... ) while i do the value get confuses.. Can i do that in same page ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73034/discussion-between-user4671040-and-dhiraj-bodicherla).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by mayanktum you forgot to add jQuery. Also in the last line you mistakenly named the selector `$(".sum1")` instead of `$(".sum_1");`. After that all works fine.

```
$(document).on("change", ".1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".sum_1").val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second fiddle you referred to `$(".sum1")` when in fact your class is named sum_1 (not sum1). Also the jQuery library need to be added in jsfiddle